# async await into actionCreator, should i return the result?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, fetch, state

Into my actionCreators I call some rest API endpoints on action e.g.  `UPDATE_CART_ITEM` etc.

At first I was using axios like so `return axios()...`:

```
export const login = (username, password) => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(requestLogin())
  const URL = `${USERS_URL}?username=${username}&password=${password}`
  return axios(URL)
    .then((response) => {
      return response.data
    })
    .then((user) => {
      dispatch(loginSuccess(user))
      // save the user on localStorage
      localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user))
      // direct the logedin user to the games page
      history.push('/')
    })
    .catch(() => {
      return dispatch(loginFailure())
    })
}
```

Now I use async/await like so:

```
// On payload i have the obj: {prId: 'xxxxx'}
export const updateCartItem = (payload) => async (dispatch) => {
    const response = await fetch('cart/update',
    {
      body: JSON.stringif(payload),
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      method: 'POST',
    })

  // I m not sure if i have to return the result
  const result = await response.json()

  // I dispatch the action with the payload
  await dispatch(return {
    payload,
    type: UPDATE_CART_ITEM,
  })
} catch (err) {
  dispatch(cartActionFail(err))
}
 }
```

So, inside the `updateCartItem` function, how should I handle the `result` ?
Since I'm passing `payload` to the reducer, it seems that I don't need it.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to do something like this:

`dispatch({ payload: response, type: UPDATE_CART_ITEM })`

`dispatch(return { /*...*/ })` doesn't make sense as far as I know, and `dispatch()` doesn't return a promise so there's no point in awaiting on it.

In general, if you want to replace promise chains with async/await, then you want to replace `foo.then(bar => { baz(bar); })` with `const bar = await foo; baz(bar);`

Answer (score 1):

If you need to consume your result immediatly, then you should dispatch an action like UPDATE_CART_ITEM_SUCCEED, otherwise do nothing.

BTW, I recommend you to use redux-saga or redux-thunk to handle your app side effects such as API calls.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the same payload for your action creator what happens if something goes wrong at your backend? Your backend side won't change but your state won't be aware of that and updates itself with payload. This is why you should use some error check here. Also, personally I use last result as a payload to my action creators, not the original payload.

```
export const updateCartItem = payload => async ( dispatch ) => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(
      "cart/update",
      {
        body: JSON.stringif( payload ),
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        method: "POST",
      }
    );
    if ( !response.ok ) { throw new Error( "response error" ); }
    const result = await response.json();
    return dispatch( {
      payload: result,
      type: UPDATE_CART_ITEM,
    } );
  } catch ( error ) {
    return dispatch( cartActionFail( error.message ) );
  }
};
```

You can change and enhance this logic according to your needs. As @vkarpov15 pointed out dispatch does not use `return` explicitly and it does not return a promise, hence you don't need await there.

Comment: Indeed on that case i can use 'result' as a payload. But isn't try{}catch() give me the error is something happen on the backend ?

Comment: I've edited my answer. Yes you are right if error happens try/catch will catch this but without any error if something goes wrong your state will change somehow. Of course this is just a personal way to handle the logic. Using result like this is my preference since I can see what comes back to my state.